# How to calculate number of nodes in binary trees in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree, nodes

So I came up with this code, not sure how to continue.

```
treeSize :: (Integral b) => BinaryTree a -> b
treeSize tree = case tree of
    Null -> 0
    Node _ t1 t2 ->
```

Comment: `Node _ t1 t2 -> treeSize t1 + 1 + treeSize t2`. And you really only need `Num b`, not `Integral b`.

Comment: `Num b` is the most general type, but I think `Integral b` is an equally useful type, and more informative about what result values are actually possible.

Comment: @Alec please make your comment an answer so OP can accept as the right answer.

Comment: @PieOhPah I made a community wiki answer. Feel free to edit it if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The last case just needs to be `Node _ t1 t2 -> 1 + treeSize t1 + treeSize t2`. Also, the `Integral b` constraint gives you more than you need - `Num b` is enough in this case.

```
treeSize :: Num b => BinaryTree a -> b
treeSize Null = 0
treeSize (Node _ t1 t2) = 1 + treeSize t1 + treeSize t2
```